# ESP8266 - Terminal Connection not working but Python script

Tags: ubuntu, serial-port, arduino, wifi, iot

I have connected an ESP8266 Wifi to serial module to a serial to USB connector.

I am able to connect to the ESP8266 with following Python script and settings:

```
import serial

def echoCommand(cmd,expected_return,halt_on_fail,tOut = timeoutPeriod) :
    ser.write(cmd + '\r\n')

    if(echo_local_command):
        print('Sent --> '+cmd)

    if not echoFind(expected_return,tOut) and (halt_on_fail):
        print(cmd+" failed")
        sys.exit()

def echoFind(expected_return,tOut):
    timeoutTime = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(0,tOut)
    while datetime.datetime.now() < timeoutTime:
        while ser.inWaiting():
            ret = ser.readline().rstrip()
            print ret
            time.sleep(0.1)
            if expected_return in ret:
                return True
    return False 

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=5)

echoCommand('AT+RST', 'ready', True)
```

The above works like a charm but for some reason I can not do the same in a terminal like minicom , GTKTerm , Putty.(Running Ubuntu. Any suggested terminals that will display CR and LF?)

I used the same baud rate and settings but with no luck. I have tried to switch hardware and software flow control and have checked CR and LF to be added.

Any ideas why this would not work?

I have noticed that if I have minicom open and then run the Python script that the output from the ESP8266 gets displayed in minicom indicating and sending issue.(Script fails cause minicom intercepts the incoming messages)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right... I found a solution to this issue. The problem was that the ESP8266 needs CR + LF after each AT command to respond.

To do this with Putty you need to press Ctrl+M and Ctrl+J to manually insert the CR+LF. As an alternative, the Arduino IDE - Serial window can be used as it allows you to automatically add CR+LF.(The Arduino IDE also works on most OS's)

Comment: Bertus! I wish I could donate reputation to you for that post. I have been trying four hours to get good commands sent. I was sending simple AT+RST to my esp's and getting and echo back plus "ERROR". All I had to do was turn on append cr-lf in Termite 3.1. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to the mentioned above CR+LF issue, some boards have DTR connected to ESP8266 GPIO in order to upload firmware, so your terminal program should not pull DTR low in order for ESP8266 to respond properly.

You can either disconnect DTR while not updating firmware, or try another terminal program which does not use DTR for control.

Answer (score 2):

If a GUI is ok, `cutecom` on linux has a setting to use CR/LF line endings

If you need a terminal picocom can work

```
$ picocom --omap crcrlf /dev/ttyUSB0
```